# mouse listener to JLabels

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

stuck here for days....what is wrong here pls tell

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at contacts3.<init>(contacts3.java:41)
    at contacts3.main(contacts3.java:75)
```

part of my code---

```
contacts3()
{
    try
    {
        f1=new JFrame();
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:login321", "", "");
        Statement st=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String fet="Select * from Contacts";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(fet);
        int i=0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            l[i]=new JLabel(rs.getString(1));
            l[i].setFont(ft);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("acccc");
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(500,1));
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
    {
        p1.add(l[i]);
        l[i].addMouseListener(this);
    }

    f1.getContentPane().add(p1);
    f1.setSize(600,300);
    f1.setVisible(true);

}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
{
    try
    {
        JLabel label=(JLabel)m.getSource();
        //new convall(label.getText());
        f1.dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("avc");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point to lines where you have exception?

Comment: You're trying to use `l[i]` unconditionally up to 500. It looks like you don't have that many.

Comment: @kiheru Yes but this wouldn't generate a `NullPointerException`, this would generate a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @BackSlash sure it does. If the array is initialized to size 500, but the values inside are not, the first unitialized throws an NPE when used.

Comment: @kiheru It's not what you said in your first comment, you said _It looks like you don't have that many_, it means _out of bounds_ to me, not _uninitialized array values_

Comment: @BackSlash it's an array, not a List. Having less than expected means the rest are uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your code is erroring out on this line

```
p1.add(l[i]);
```

Where do you initialize your array l?  Also you only set the first n records of that array where n is the number of Rows in your ResultSet.  But later you add the first 500 elements of the array.  Do you get at least 500 elements from the SQL query?